# Spark merging two single value datasets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset with the following schema

```
|-- Name: string (nullable = true)
|-- Values: long (nullable = true)
|-- Count: integer (nullable = true)
```

Input Dataset

```
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+                           
|Name        |Values                 |Count         |
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+
|A           |1000                   |1             |
|B           |1150                   |0             |
|C           |500                    |3             |
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

My result dataset needs to be of the format

```
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+                           
|Sum(count>0)|      sum(all)         | Percentage   |
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+
|    1500    |      2650             | 56.60        |
+------------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

I am currently able to get the sum(count>0) and sum(all) in individual datasets by running

```
val non_zero = df.filter(col(COUNT).>(0)).select(sum(VALUES).as(NON_ZERO_SUM))
val total = df.select(sum(col(VALUES)).as(TOTAL_SUM))
```

I'm at a loss on what to do to merge the two independent datasets into a single dataset, with which I would calculate the percentage.

Also could this same problem be solved in a better way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use single aggregation:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(
  sum(when($"count" > 0, $"values')).alias("NON_ZERO_SUM"),
  sum($"values").alias("TOTAL_SUM")
)
```